# How to search based on createdDate and other fields in elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
     host: 'ABC',
     log: 'trace'
});

client.search({
index: 'allevents_production',
"body": {
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "clientname",
            "query": 'ser'
        },
        "range" : {
            "createddate" : {
                "gte" : "now-1d/d",
                "lt" :  "now/d"
            }
        }
    }
}
})
```

I want to search on the multiple fields like **client name** and **createddate**. I passed these fields in the body part.

> It returns an error. Please help me where I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your mapping and the detailed error to your question please ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine both constraints using [`bool/must/filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):

```
client.search({
index: 'allevents_production',
"body": {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "clientname",
            "query": "ser"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "createddate": {
              "gte": "now-1d/d",
              "lt": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
})
```

Comment: it returning error `{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
                "line": 12,
                "col": 5
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 12,
        "col": 5
    },
    "status": 400
}`

Comment: Bad copy/paste, sorry, fixed.